# Activity Stack full: OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

My App is designed with a side menu, so that basically you can start any Activity from any Activity. If I start the activity with the default behaviour of the back stack of Android, the Activities get stacked on each other until the memory of the phone is full and it results in a very scary

> 02-09 15:43:12.807 1860-1868/? E/System: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Now my questions are:

1. Should I launch the activities with another launch mode (REORDER_TO_FRONT, CLEAR_TOP), but all that stuff makes the back button behavior worse?
2. Would the GC actually collect some Activities if the memory gets to full, and my problem is maybe I just have some strong references pointing to them left, making them unable to get cleared from memory?

Can someone explain please, thank you!

Comment: 1. no, 2 yes ... an I would follow this path for future investigation ... but obviously withotu code it is just blind guess.

Comment: 2 is also by far my prefered solution, then I can start looking for the leaks...

Comment: What I want to say is if there are still references that prevent the GC from collecting my activities I can look for them myself, I just wanted to ask if this will eventually really clear some memory again or the activities will stay on the stack forever anyway.

Comment: The stack will be reconstructed, memory leaks will be actually references from code, the stack will go onDestroy and onCreate again returning

Comment: Remove the long size(above 800) of an image from our project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an activity is put on the back stack, Android usually keeps the instance in memory. When the memory is low, back stack activities are shut down (this includes calling [`onSaveInstanceState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))      [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy())), but the system keeps the information needed to recreate them, in case the user navigates back.
The retained information is small and should not be a problem, unless you have hundred of activities stacked. On the other hand, once destroyed, the activity instance will never be reused and must be garbage-collectable, otherwise it constitutes a Context leaks, [which mays not be obvious to spot](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html).

A few suggestions :

1. Enable [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) and in particular [detectActivityLeaks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder.html#detectActivityLeaks()) to detect Activity (and other Android's objects) leaks

   ```
   StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
           .detectActivityLeaks()

           // or even
           .detectAll()

           .penaltyLog()
           // or
           .penaltyDeath()

           .build());
   ```
2. Use Android Studio's memory profiler. [Heap dumps](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html#capture-heap-dump) can show you where references are held. The older memory monitor had analyzer tasks to find leaked activities. As far as I know there is no equivalent in Android Studio 3.0
3. Try with and without enabling the *Don't keep activities* option in the device's developer options. Enabling it makes the activities lifecycle more predictable.
4. Use a library like [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I need to know. Thank you.