# Process: com.android.vending throws OutOfMemoryError while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory, google-play-console

I started receiving such type of errors during testing at Google Play Console:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.vending, PID: 2389
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

and:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
Process: com.android.vending, PID: 6615
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

on such device - K3 2017 with 1024Mb RAM. I know that you will suggest me to add such lines at manifest:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

but these errors I received also after adding these lines to my manifest. Maybe someone knows how to solve such type of error?

Comment: Did you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219530/how-to-fix-outofmemoryerror-thrown-while-trying-to-throw-outofmemoryerror-with-r

Comment: @intellignt_idiot, no I didn't see it, but can you explain me what means 2 and 4 items of first answer? because I've never see `@Streaming` usage at retrofit and I don't know what is it :(

Comment: For 4 check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: For 2 - It means add this @Streaming annotation above the method in which you are receiving the response.
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=retrofit.http.Streaming

Comment: @intellignt_idiot, at this question as I see it better for me not use logging at body level, but how I will see received data?)

Comment: Try other solutions.  It could be due to one of these reasons :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708441/activity-stack-full-outofmemoryerror

Comment: Ultimately you have to test it yourself on a device which has low RAM.This will give you an indication as to what or which class or activity is causing this issue.